# Delete rows based on multiple columns and multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet, and I'm trying. to write VBA code to delete rows from the excel sheet based on the following conditions:
If Column A contains strings "string1" and "string2".
OR
If Column B contains strings "string3" or "string4"

Im using the below code:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim pos As Integer
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        pos = InStr(LCase(rng.Item(i).Value), "string1"))
        If pos > 0 Then
            rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

But it only deletes rows if the single string is located in any column , and I couldn't specify the column name to search in.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

With `rng.Cells.Count` you loop through all cells in the range:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = rng.Columns(2).Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
```

will only loop through the cells of column 2.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your Loop - you're looping through each `Item` in the range, rather than each row

Try the below

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rownum As Long
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    
    For rownum = rng.rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If LCase(Rng.Cells(rownum, 1) Like "*String1*" And _
        LCase(rng.Cells(rownum, 1) Like "*String2*" Or _
        LCase(rng.Cells(rownum, 2) Like "*String3*" Or _
        LCase(rng.Cells(rownum, 2) Like "*String4*" Then
            rng.Cells(rownum, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `rownum` needs to be of type `Long`. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in the example above, if "string11" exists not "string1" the algorithm will delete the entire row as well.. any advice, please?

Comment: That's because `"String11"` contains `"String1"` - the only fix here is to tweak your criteria, but not knowing the data we cant help you much. Perhaps if the separate strings have a space or other character in between them you could search for `"String1 "` ?